# How to switch from a ViewController back to the second tab of a TabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

My app has a TabBarController in which on the second Tab has a button in which pressed takes the user to a new ViewController. I would like to know if its possible to move from the ViewController presented after the button is clicked back to the second tab of the TabBarController. Right now my app is able to go back to the TabBarController but it just presents the view from the first tab rather than the second. Currently I just have the segues setup from the main.storyboard in order to go back to the TabBarController.

Comment: Can you provide some code/screen captures about your problem? Because when you tapped on a `TabBarController`  button, the tapped button is automatically selected using segues.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the selected index:

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```